# What is the correct spelling of the head of the Derbytantes group?

Tags: powerpuff-girls

*Powerpuff Girls 2016* season 1 episode 2 Princess Buttercup has a group of skaters called the Derbytantes.  This group is led by a girl whose name is pronounced something like /ˈmeɪlən/ or /ˈmeɪlɪn/.  What is the correct spelling of the name of that character?

I checked the credits listing at the end of the episode, and it doesn't seem to include her name.

If possible, I'd like canonical information, or at least information from the creators of the show.  If such information is absolutely unavailable, I can accept an educated guess from someone who knows more about the English language than me.

(Possible spellings include Maelin, Maylen, Maylin, Maylyn, Meiling)

**Update:** Richard is right of course, but to make me look slightly less stupid, let me note that I really did look at the credits.  It looked like this.

[image: (lower quality screenshot from credits, listing the voices, with “Maylyn: Kate Higgins”)]

It totally says “Mayor: Kate Higgins” there.  You can't have credits without listing the Mayor, right?

(In reality, the Mayor is voiced by Tom Kenny, and doesn't appear in E2.  The girls' phones ring, but they don't pick it up, because they can see the giant monster from where they are.)

Comment: You should have looked harder at the credits... :-)

Comment: I'll grant you that the exact spelling cannot be gleaned from that screenshot, but it very clearly ends in an n and thus cannot possibly say _Mayor_. In the squished version you've got here, it looks to me as though it says _Matzin_, but even English wouldn't be likely to spell /ˡmeɪlɪn/ in quite such a bizarre fashion.

Comment: Also, +1 for good and proper use of IPA!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the credits at the end of the episode, it's Maylyn.

[image]

Comment: Hand-drawn red circle: +1.

Comment: @SQB - I feel like I should have added some arrows as well.

Comment: Reupload it. You could make the lines a bit thicker as well.

Answer (score 2):

The best source I could find was the [Powerpuff Girls Wikia](http://powerpuffgirls.wikia.com/wiki/Derbytantes), which says her name is **Maylyn**:

> Every member of the Derbytantes has a nickname that ends with "-lyn".
>
> Maylyn (Voice actor: Kate Higgins) is the leader of the Derbytantes. Every conversation of the gang is brought forth by Maylyn.
>
> Jaylyn looks pretty much identical to most members of the group.
>
> Bobbysuzeraelyn has undeniably the most extraordinary appearance out of all members in the gang. Her appearance has all the features of a full grown man, yet she speaks with a very girly voice.
>
> "Buttlyn" is Buttercup's nickname as a member of the Derbytantes.

Obviously Wikia isn't a canonical source, but this spelling makes sense since many girls' names in English end with "lyn". The names [Catelyn](http://www.thinkbabynames.com/meaning/0/Catelyn), [Kathryn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kathryn), and [Lynn](http://www.behindthename.com/name/lynn) are all reasonably common.

(Admittedly several of the other possible spellings you propose would also make sense, but in the absence of better evidence, all we have is Maylyn.)

Comment: I'd like to note that Buttercup says the names of all members "rhyme with 'lin' ", not that they "end with 'lin' ".